# Downloading a binary file from a bytea field in postgres

Tags: postgresql, binary, binaryfiles, psql

I successfully put a binary file (a jpg) into a bytea field in postgres, with the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE file_locker_test
(
ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
THE_FILE_ITSELF bytea
);


INSERT INTO file_locker_test (ID, THE_FILE_ITSELF)
VALUES (1, bytea('\\Users\\My Name\\Pictures\\picture.jpg'));
```

Now, I'm trying to download the file back to make sure that it has uploaded correctly.

I tried this:

```
\copy (SELECT encode(file_locker_test(the_file_itself), 'hex') FROM file_locker_test LIMIT 1) TO '\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\picture.hex';
```

And got this error:

```
//Users/My Name/Desktop/picture.hex: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused.

1. The `INSERT` didn't insert the binary file, but the (binary) string `\\Users\\My Name\\Pictures\\picture.jpg`.
2. The file `/Users/My Name/Desktop/picture.hex` cannot be created on the database server, probably because one of the directories on the path does not exist.

If you want to insert the content of the binary file into the database, you'll have to write a program that opens and reads the file into memory and then inserts that.

Comment: Ah ok -- so I will have to use psycopg2 and Python it seems?  I am having trouble with the connection string.

Comment: Python would work. Any language with a PostgreSQL interface.